# How to avoid duplicates for SUM( CASE WHEN ..THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I ghave following query:

```
            SELECT col.myId,
                   SUM( CASE WHEN tu.userId IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS uCount,
                   SUM( CASE WHEN g.grouptype != 12 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS gCount
            FROM myUserTable col
                     LEFT JOIN fooTable elem ON col.myId = elem.myId
                     LEFT JOIN barTable esc ON elem.anotherId = esc.anotherId
                     LEFT JOIN userTable tu ON esc.anotherId = tu.anotherId
                     LEFT JOIN grouTable g ON g.groupid = tu.groupid
            GROUP BY col.myId
```

The problem here that duplicated `userId` is counted twice. I want to avoid it.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT tu.userId) AS uCount,
```

Comment: null will be ignored ?

Comment: one more question.


what if conditiona a bit more complex:

`SUM( CASE WHEN tu.userId IS  NULL AND g.grouptype != 12 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @gstackoverflow . . . This does not count `NULL` values.  As for your second comment, there is no utility in counting distinct values of something that is not `NULL`, so the `SUM()` may do what you want.